# Need to remove the clone element in html5 drag and drop

Tags: html, ember.js, html5-draggable

I have a div element which I am able to drag however I wish to drop it in a specific div element. Here, I need to remove the dragged cloned element div while drag and also the original dragged element shouldn't be change.

I used a custom helper div while dragging. Here, how can I remove the cloned dragged element?

I'm using the below code,

```
dragStart: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
},
drag: function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    var self = this; 
    var posi_left = event.originalEvent.clientX;
    var posi_right = event.originalEvent.clientY;
    $('#helperdiv').css({'left': posi_left, 'top': posi_right });
},

drop: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

JSBIN LINK: [JSBIN DEMO](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fomenisuge/1/edit?html,js,output)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "cloned dragged element" ?

Comment: @Ajey I have updated my post with the attached screenshot.